# trying to load php file with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i am new to ajax i am trying to build a website for movies so i need ajax to change the servers for the video but i can not do it how much i tried the div that i want to show is not being shown at all here is my codes

> HTML

```
    <?php
$get = $data->show(" SELECT * FROM servers ");
foreach ($get as $row) {
 $id=$row['server_id'];
 $name=$row['server_name'];
 $link=$row['link'];
 $movie=$row['film_name'];


?>
            <button type="button" id="btn" class="btn btn-warning"><?php echo "$name"; ?></button> 
            <input type="hidden" id="serverid" value="<?php echo $id ?>">
        <?php } ?>
<div id="show">

</div>
```

> AJAX

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (){

        $('#btn').click(function (){
var serverid = $('#serverid').val()


$.ajax({
    url:"../../control/operation/index/view_movie.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{serverid:serverid},
    success:function(data)
    {
$("#show").html(data);
    }
});

        });
    });
</script>
```

> view_movie.php

```
    if (isset($_POST['serverid'])) {

    $id=$_POST['serverid'];
    $getuser = $data->getdata(" SELECT * FROM servers WHERE server_id='$id' ");
    $link=$getuser['link'];


} ?>




<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
          <div class="col-md-8"> 
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="<?php echo $link ?>" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
          </div>
```

nothing is shown on the div that called show

Comment: IDs _must_ be unique within an HTML document.

Comment: The hidden field is superfluous here anyway - `button` has a `value` attribute, too, so you can place the server id into that, and read it back from there.

Comment: @CBroe before i try the hidden input i tried the button value but still same result also i tried `getElementById`

Comment: You can not put the same ID on multiple of those buttons either; trying to select them by ID will only ever get you the very first one.

Comment: @CBroe i know that this is just a test to see if it works or not so i just need a random id but it dont seems to work

Comment: Well then you’ll need to do some basic debugging. What have you done so far in that regard?

Comment: i removed the php code to see if it will work with out it or not i put some normal texts still it didnt show in the div 
i tried to get the ajax classes online and offline still did not work

Comment: What does the browser console say? How does the request get answered when you check it in the network panel?

Comment: i got some errors like `viewmovie.php not found ` `EER_BLOCKED_BY_CLINT`  and in the network says the ` ID blocked others ` im sure the path to viewmovie.php is right i checked it multiple times and double checked again now

Comment: Now which one is it, a 404 NOT FOUND, or ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT? The latter usually means some browser extension blocked stuff. Try in a private browser window, without any extensions enabled, and see if you still get the same result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213160/discussion-between-mhamad-aras-and-cbroe).

Comment: i tried on a private still did not work
the embeded player is the ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT also the ID says failed 
  to response data also the 404 NOT found was a picture that i removed before